# The distribution of the sum of a uniform random variable and a binomial random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm asked to find the distribution of $U=X+Z$, where

$X\widetilde~R(0,1)$ - That is, $X$ has a uniform distribution for $x\in]0;1[$

$Z\widetilde~bin(1,1/2)$ - That is, $Z$ has a binomial distribution and $P(Z=0)=P(Z=1)=1/2$

How do I find the distribution of $U=X+Z?$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to prove that $U$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,2)\setminus\{1\}=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.

Comment: How do I know it's distributed over $(0,2)$?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{Supp}(X+Y)\subseteq\operatorname{Supp}(X)+\operatorname{Supp}(Y)$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If $X$ belongs to $(0,1)$ and $Y$ belongs to $\{0,1\}$, what do you expect the outcomes of $X+Y$ to be?

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!

Comment: If intuition is not clear, we can compute. Let our sum be $W$. We go after the cumulative distribution function  of $W$, by conditioning on $Z$. Given that $Z=0$, we have $F_W(w)=\Pr(W\le w)=w$ if $0\lt w\lt 1$. It is also easy to describe the conditional cdf of $W$ if $w\le 0$ and if $w\ge 1$. Do the same sort of thing given that $Z=1$. 
Now put things together. If $w\le 0$ then $F_W(w)=0$. If $0\lt w\le 1$, then $\Pr(W\le w)=\frac{w}{2}$. If $1\lt w\lt 2$ then $F_w(w)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(w-1)=\frac{w}{2}$. And finally if $w\ge 2$ then $F_W(w)=1$.  So $W$ is uniform on $(0,2)$.

Comment: You are welcome. I wrote this to show that we can grind it out if necessary.