# Convolution of a Binomial and Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I am given that $X$ is a random variable with a Binomial distribution with parameters $(n,p)$ and that $Y$ is a random variable with a Uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. We assume independence. I want to find the distribution of the sum of $X$ and $Y$.

First, I define $Z:=X+Y$ and I want to find $F_z(z)=P(Z\le z)$.

Now, I understand how to go about this problem if $X$ and $Y$ are both discrete or both continuous, however in this case $X$ is discrete while $Y$ is continuous. For example, if I had two continuous distributions then:

$P(Z\le z) = P(X+Y\le z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty}f_X(z-x) f_Y(y) dy$

Do I need to transform the pmf of $X$ into a continuous function and if so how can I do this? This is supposedly an easy question so perhaps there is a very straightforward way.

Comment: Nitpick: I think you meant “I want to find the distribution of the *sum* of  and .” The *distributions* get convolved; the *variables* are added.

Comment: Yes, edited the original post, thanks.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113762

Comment: I think you can be as well inspired by this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169353 that rightly promotes the idea to use Dirac's $$\delta$s ; but are you familiar with these notations ?

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you. I'm not familiar with that at all, but very happy to learn. My only concern is that since I have not encountered this before, I doubt this is the intended way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the distribution without thinking about convolutions at all: Note that if you know the value of $Z$, say $Z=z$, then with probability $1$, $X=\lfloor z\rfloor$ (the greatest integer $\le z$) and $Y=Z-X$. So the probability density on the interval $(k,k+1)$ will just be $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

If you *do* wish to think of convolution, do a formal calculation with delta functions: The distribution of $X$ is given by
$$ f_X(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \delta(x-k), $$
and that of $Y$ by $f_Y(y)=[0<y<1]$ (where the bracket is the [Iverson bracket](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468340/how-widely-known-are-iverson-brackets)), hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
  f_X*f_Y(z)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,dx \\
   &= \int_{z-1}^{z} f_X(x) \,dx \\
   &= \int_{z-1}^{z} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \delta(x-k) \,dx \\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \int_{z-1}^{z} \delta(x-k) \,dx \\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \bigl[z-1<k<z\bigr] \\
   &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \bigl[k<z<k+1\bigr]
\end{aligned}
$$
(again using the Iverson bracket at the end). That final expression is just a restatement of what I said in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, this has really made it clear to me. Would I be right in saying that the Iverson bracket is equivalent to an indicator function on the event inside the bracket?

Comment: Yes it is. It avoids difficult-to-read information in lower case as indices.